# How to handle object mutations in Vuex at once

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an object in `vuex`:

```
state () {
    return {
        generalInfo: {
            userName: 'Bla',
            firtsName: 'Bla',
            lastName: 'Bla'
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this object in a component with the use of a computed property like so:

```
computed: {
    generalInfo: {
        get() {
            return this.$store.getters['profile/generalInfo']
        },
        set(newVal) {
            this.$store.commit('profile/setProfileInfo', newVal)
        }
        
    }
},
```

As you can see I've made a mutation in my `store` that handles the mutation of my object:

```
mutations: {
    setProfileInfo(state, obj) {
        state.generalInfo.userName = obj.userName
        state.generalInfo.firstName = obj.firstName
        state.generalInfo.lastName = obj.lastName
    }
},
```

But for some reason `vuex` still keeps complaining about setting states outside a `vuex` mutation. When I do this per object item (i.e. I'm setting a computed property on `generalInfo.UserName` with a corresponding mutation handler) things work just fine but I don't want to do it on every seperate object item...

I'm using `vuex`4 (next)

Comment: You have a typo in `firtsName`

Comment: If you are mutating `generalInfo.userName` in your component - Vuex will emit a warning. You should assign new object to the `generalInfo` computed property instead of mutating the individual properties of `generalInfo` because in this case your setter (and hence the Vuex mutation) won't be called.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I did what you said but it still keeps complaining about mutating outside store

Comment: Hm, then you can look at the stacktrace of the error and place a breakpoint on the first item of the stacktrace. Then, when the breakpoint fires - you should explore the callstack in DevTools and try to trace back to some of your own functions where the code actually mutates `generalInfo` outside of Vuex.